# Weierstrass theorem problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, factorial

Study the convergence of the series:

$$a_n=\frac{a^2}{n!}\text{ where } a>0$$

So I thought that we should have multiple cases:

**Case 1:** $a\in (0,1)$

**Case 2**: $a>1$   but I am not really sure because I know how to find the limit of it and I have done it like that. Can someone help?

Comment: Series or sequence?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^2}{n!}=0$$
for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof.* Note that
$$\left|\frac{a^2}{n!}\right|\leq\frac{a^2}{n}.$$
Let $\epsilon>0$. Take $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $N>a^2/\epsilon$. Then, for all $n\geq N$ we have $a^2/n\leq a^2/N<\epsilon$. $\square$